# Web application with Intellij Idea 14 and Gradle

Tags: jakarta-ee, web, intellij-idea, build, gradle

We have ported a web project to Gradle and we are now trying to use it in Intellij Idea 14.0. But I'm a little confused! Gradle tool window is there and the tasks works properly. 
As far as I understood, even when the project is based on Gradle, Idea uses its own project files to manage things. However, these project files are updated from Gradle when "Refresh all Gradle projects" button in the Gradle tool window is pressed.

1. Idea web facet is NOT automatically created from Gradle. So the artifact of the project is not created correctly. Am I missing something?
2. Is there anyway to change Idea make, build artifact (in Build menu) to work based on Gradle tasks instead of Idea's own project files? (for example somehow telling Idea that Make in Build menu should simply run compile task of Gradle or Build Artficat should run build task of Gradle?)
3. How should I create proper Run/Debug configurations? I tried the following sequence:
   `Gradle Build Project`
   `Build Artifacts`
   But when invoking my Run configuration, no real artifact is built (i.e. the output directory for the artifact remains empty) which results in nothing deployed in Tomcat!

Comment: For question 1, it's hard to understand without knowing your IDEA14 settings. In Settings>Build>Gradle, do you have "Use default gradle wrapper" checked? Or are you using your own local install of gradle?

Comment: For question3: your build artifacts should be in your root/build/libs. Also note, if you just want to build, call the assemble target (not build) because build will also run run unit tests. Also, everytime you run one of these targets, you should see them added to the "run dropdown" in the "tool buttons" area at the top of your screen.

Comment: For the question in the intro: yes, IDEA tracks its own things. And if you make changes to your gradle build file (ex: you change a dependency lib version), then you need to tell IDEA to refresh itself so that it can highlight your code (errors, etc) based on the new lib versions. That's when you'd hit that refresh button.

Comment: Have you added `apply plugin: 'war'` to build.gradle?

Comment: Also Java EE — (Servlets, JSP, JSF, Web Services, CDI, Bean Validation, etc.) [Supported only in Ultimate Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)